# File.write will not allow me to add to the textfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

In my class, my instructor went over code to add names to a text file and to identify an IOError if one occurs. I copied the code he wrote exactly. It worked for him but not for me. The only difference I can think of is that he was using an older version of Python (it was an online video from 2017, doing online classes). I am currently using Python 3.8. Here is the code:

```
try:
    file = open("namesList.txt", "a")
    file.write("EOF")
except IOError:
    print("IO Error")
    file.close()
else:
    print("EOF written successfully")
    file.close()
```

I have tried pulling the code out of the try block to see if that works, but no errors popped up. It will still print "EOF written successfully" while in the try block and outside of it, but in the text file "EOF" does not show up.

I hope I explained it well enough, let me know if I need to clarify anything else. Thank you!

Comment: Code is working there is no issue with your code. You text file is empty ?

Comment: Not reproducible, see working [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/GuiltyBurlywoodSystemresource#main.py)

Comment: I see it work in the live demo, but for whatever reason it doesn't work on my computer. The text file remains empty, yes.

Answer (score 1):

JessDee, the code is working for me as it is.

In any case, I think you should consider using the **with** statement when working with files.

It's cleaner, it's more pythonic. That way, you don't need to worry about closing the file. Python will do it for you.

I don't know if it will fix your problem, but it's something to consider.

This would be your code using **with** statement:

```
try:
    with open("namesList.txt", "a+") as file:
        file.write("EOF")
        print("EOF written successfully")
except IOError:
    print("IO Error")
```

Notice I used **a+** instead of **a**. This means it will be opened in write/read mode.

Since we don't know the exact nature of your problem, I don't know if it will solve it, but it'll help you from now on. Good luck !